# Pass value from Java action class to ejb?

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

I have developed a web application. I put session id in hashtable. I want to use this hash table in ejb. Means I want to use this login session in ejb.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: is it ejb 2, ejb 3.0 or ejb 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not impossible, but you must not do it. Get everything you need from the `HttpSession` and send it to the EJB as method parameters. For example:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String foo = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("foo");
    ejbService.doSomething(foo);
}
```

So -  pass the values you need as parameters to methods, through the chain layers of your application.

Comment: Why can't he use the security context? Should be no need to pass extra parameters.

Comment: actually my application is flow is look like

Comment: StrutsAction--->Service--->EJBClient-->BusinessLogic-->DataAccess      i want to make some database side logic depends on login session so i stored that session in hashtable in Action class . And now i want this hashtable in my bussiness logic (In ejb side)...

Answer (score 0):

Security credentials are passed automatically from servlet to EJB. If your user has authenticated to the Web Container then you don't need to do any work yourelf.

In the session bean get the EjbContext as described [link text](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/4-ways-to-get-ejbcontext-in-ejb-3.html)

```
 @Resource
 private SessionContext sctx;
```

and then call methods such as

```
 sctx.getCallerPrincipal();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant. I assume he wants to pass any http session param to the ejb. Furthermore, it is good to separate the client (web layer) and the service (ejb layer), rather than mixing them together.

Comment: actually my application is flow is look like                          StrutsAction--->Service--->EJBClient-->BusinessLogic-->DataAccess i want to make some database side logic depends on login session so i stored that session in hashtable in Action class . And now i want this hashtable in my bussiness logic (In ejb side)...

Comment: yes u are absolutely ri8.. and i also follow this rules strictly but how can i achive   this ......??

Comment: by passing the values as parameters to methods, through the chain